# Detect touch device on C# MVC Razor

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, razor, touch

I tried to use user agent to detect but it can't detect all touch screen (like surface, laptop with touch screen,...), it just can detect mobile device like phone, tablet. Any solution?

Comment: Have you tried this snippet: Request.Browser["IsTouchScreen"] ?